# How to make an API call from parent and return result to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<Parent />` component which has a text field and a button, and I have the button's value handled by recompose's `withState` and `withHandlers`. When I click the button, I make a fetch call to my server, which in a few seconds returns a bunch of data (usually an array of length ~10,000). I then store this data in another `withState`. However, the problem arises now that when I try to type in the text field, it lags heavily, since local state/props is updating a multi-thousand item array every time I hit a key.

To solve this, I want to create a `<Results />` component, but I can't figure out the proper way to do this. The button should ideally live in the Parent component, since it's part of the user input, and the result should only really have result-related things. I can't store the result in Parent and pass it to Results, since storing it in Parent is the whole problem. What's the 'proper' way, architecturally speaking, to have the button in Parent, but have the results from the API call only be loaded in Results component?

Comment: you cannot paginate the data?

Comment: @DanielLizik No, I want to plot it in charts and such, which requires the full dataset.

Comment: this is besides your point but I would just summarize/average the data into a smaller amount of data points, and if the user wants to increase granularity (i.e., zoom into a particular section) then increase the amount of data points for a subsection of your total dataset.

Comment: as for your actual question, i wouldn't put a huge store in `state`. use a data wrapper component (or redux/mobx/etc) to load the data, then send it to your actual views as `props`, not `state`